# Can somebody explain to me why these terms are equal?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, exponential-function, trigonometric-series

I just read a proof on [ProofWiki](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Euler%27s_Formula#Proof_3) that proves Euler's formula, but I can't seem to understand what is done in this following step:

$$\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{(i\theta)^{2n}}{(2n)!}+\frac{(i\theta)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}\right) =\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty{\frac{(i\theta)^n}{n!}}$$

Could anyone help me understand this equality step by step?

Comment: Note that 1st and 2nd term on LHS are even and odd terms on the RHS respectively. Then the equality is follows.

Comment: As always I've tried to keep my answer as simple as possible.  I am the local worshipper of simplicity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. You understand, I assume, that the first term is the $\cos$ function, and the second term is the $\sin$ function. Try plugging in values of $n$, and see what emerges.
$$n=0: \frac{(i\theta)^{2\cdot0}}{(2\cdot0)!}=\frac{(i\theta)^{0}}{0!}$$
$$n=0: \frac{(i\theta)^{2\cdot0+1}}{(2\cdot0+1)!}=\frac{(i\theta)^{1}}{1!}$$
$$n=1: \frac{(i\theta)^{2\cdot1}}{(2\cdot1)!}=\frac{(i\theta)^{2}}{2!}$$
$$n=1: \frac{(i\theta)^{2\cdot1+1}}{(2\cdot1+1)!}=\frac{(i\theta)^{3}}{3!}$$

Notice the pattern?
$$\frac{(i\theta)^{n}}{n!}$$
The first term ($\cos$) provides the even terms in the second sequence, and the second term ($\sin$) provides the odd terms in the second sequence. Since we are summing over an infinite sequence of integers, the upper bound doesn't have to change.

Comment: I've changed multiple instances of $a*b$ to $a\cdot b$.  The asterisk for ordinary multiplication is a workaround for occasions when one is limited to the characters on the keyboard and must reserve the lower-case x for things other than using it as a substitute for $\times$.  I also changed $sin$ and $cos$ to $\sin$ and $\cos$, coded as \sin and \cos.  That not only prevents italicization, but also provides proper spacing in things like $a\cos b$. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
n & & 2n & 2n+1 \\
\hline
0 & & 0 & 1 \\
1 & & 2 & 3 \\
2 & & 4 & 5 \\
3 & & 6 & 7 \\
4 & & 7 & 8 \\
5 & & 8 & 9 \\
6 & & 12 & 13 \\
7 & & 14 & 15 \\
\vdots & & \vdots & \vdots
\end{array}
$$
As $n$ goes through the list $0,1,2,3,4,\ldots$, the two later columns together also go through the list $0,1,2,3,4,\ldots$, each column going through half of it.  Therefore
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (a_{2n} + a_{2n+1}).
$$

Answer (score 0):

If you write out the first few terms on each side, you will see that the left side groups pairs of terms from the right side.

The idea is:
$$(a_0 + a_1) + (a_2 + a_3) + \cdots = a_0+a_1+a_2+a_3 + \cdots$$

Answer (score 0):

Just expand
$$\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{(i\theta)^{2n}}{(2n)!}+\frac{(i\theta)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}\right) =\left(\frac{1}{0!}+\frac{i\theta}{1!}\right)+\left(\frac{(i\theta)^2}{2!}+\frac{(i\theta)^3}{3!}\right)+\left(\frac{(i\theta)^4}{4!}+\frac{(i\theta)^5}{5!}\right)+\dotsb .$$ Now assuming all the nice convergence properties we can rewrite this (without the parentheses) as 
$$\text{RHS} =\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty{\frac{(i\theta)^n}{n!}}.$$